# How to make two columns into one to be responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I want to make one single column out of two, for a mobile page, but I want to keep the same content and just edit css. Is there a way to do this so when

`media="only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:125px)">` 
the two columns become one long one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using divs for your columns, you can say:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 125px) {

 #thisDiv {
   float: none;
 }

}
```

Put it in the stylesheet and it will get rid of the float that makes two columns and sets them stacked on top of each other.

You didn't post any code so this is a guess in the dark as to how your html and css is setup.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Before yesterday, I had my columns set up as divs, but I still had that problem where text in the right column would push the left one down. So then I made the divs a table and vertical-aligned them to top, and it worked, but my site was no longer responsive. So then I asked this question at like 3am and didn't realize I forgot to explain how I had things set up. Your answer did work, I just had to go back through and mess with it to get it to center and have it laid out the way I wanted. Thanks a ton though.

Comment: No problem if you're really focused on responsive design and you're like me (too stubborn to use things like bootstrap, i like to figure things out myself), then check out this article on fluid grids: http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids   and then this article on responsive design (it builds off the foundation of the fluid grids article) : http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design    These are two of the most useful articles a web designer can read in my opinion. Trust me - it's worth your time

Comment: Wow, thanks. I actually did use bootstrap, but I used their customization tool, and because that wasn't really enough, I took it into Dreamweaver and added a bunch of animations and stuff. I'm still pretty new to it, but I also want to try to keep everything smooth and responsive as well. Thanks again!